# Find the string in a array with the highest version number

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm making a simple script that versions up scripts that users are working on. This script should check the current working folder for the latest version and increment the version by 1.

Here is a example of one of the folder I'm using, this is sorted by name.

```
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_ARTIST_v001_01.comp
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_ARTIST_v005_01.comp
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_ESKI_v002_01.comp
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_ESKI_v004_01.comp
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_ESKI_v004_02.comp
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_ESKI_v004_03.comp
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_ESKI_v006_01.comp
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_ESKI_v007_01.comp
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_NEWGUY_v008_01.comp
>     TES_DAS_010_COMP_NEWGUY_v003_01.comp
```

Now I have the user ESKI that is going to version up. So I need to find a way to identify what is the latest version and increment from that.
In this example the current version is "TES_DAS_010_COMP_NEWGUY_v008_01.comp".

How can I target what file is the latest so I can make a new version that is called "TES_DAS_010_COMP_ESKI_v009_01.comp"

Comment: Seems like you have sub-version also. Are they any use? If this is all auto-generated, you could look at the latest date created.

Comment: No the subversion dont matter. The mayor version is what I'm going after.

Comment: Not a bad idea, they are all created by the script so in theory they should all have the right timestamp. I Would feel better to have it manually force check.. :)

Comment: So all you want to do is take each of those strings and increment the major  v### version number by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a basic guide for what I would do, maybe I'm missing something here but this seems like just a standard loop with converts and comparison checking right? If I'm missing a complex part here forgive me.

Iterate through the array with a loop, find the constant starting index of the version number with [indexof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx), maybe use "_v" as the search criteria, then take the [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) of the string starting at your new computed beginning indexof and ending at 3 characters later, parse/convert the three character string to a numeric, store it in a comparison variable, and check if each iteration of the loop is greater than your current highest stored. Once you're done you have your number, you could probably use linq to do it with a very small block of code.

Comment: This should do, I was just overthinking this problem.. :)

Comment: No, actually.. It would be awesome if I could sort out the highest version and get the whole string name. Guessing I'm looking for a way to do that. Probably put it in 2 column array and sort by version..?

Comment: If all you need is the highest version string - when you are storing/checking your comparison variable in your loop you could either store the entire string in an additional variable, or have the comparison variable be a dictionary or other construct and store both the currently highest comparison version number you are parsing, and then you could either store the entire string itself or the array index of the highest and do a look up on that later when you are using it. If you want it to be sortable then you could recreate the array as you are parsing with the version column to sort by.